# How to retrieve data stored from MongoDB using BSON (Python)?

Tags: python, mongodb, binary, pymongo, bson

so far in my code bellow I managed to store my data into mongoDB.
Now I want to be able to retrieve the data I have stored.
As you can see I have been trying but keep on getting an error.
With BSON do I have to first decode the data to retrieve it from mongoDB?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
(Apologies for the messy code, I am just practicing through trial and error)

```
import json
from json import JSONEncoder

import pymongo 
from pymongo import MongoClient

from bson.binary import Binary
import pickle

#Do this for each 
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)

db = client['datacampdb']
coll = db.personpractice4_collection  #creating a collection in the database 
#my collection on the database is called personpractice4_collection 

class Person:
    def __init__(self, norwegian, dame, brit, german, sweed):
        self.__norwegian = norwegian
        self.__dame = dame
        self.__brit = brit
        self.__german = german #private variable 
        self.__sweed = sweed
 
   # create getters and setters later to make OOP
 
personone = Person("norwegian", "dame", "brit", "german","sweed")  

class PersonpracticeEncoder(JSONEncoder): 
        def default(self, o):
            return o.__dict__
    

#Encode Person Object into JSON"
personpracticeJson = json.dumps(personone, indent=4, cls=PersonpracticeEncoder)
practicedata = pickle.dumps(personpracticeJson)
coll.insert_one({'bin-data': Binary(practicedata)})

#print(personpracticeJson)
#print(db.list_collection_names()) #get then names of my collections in DB 



#retriving data from mongodb 
#Retrieving a Single Document with find_one()
print(({'bin-data': Binary(practicedata)}).find_one()) #not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `find_one` method should be called on a collection

`{'bin-data': Binary(practicedata)}` is a query to find a document

```
coll.find_one({'bin-data': Binary(practicedata)})
```

Witch means : Find a document in the collection `coll` where `bin-data` is equal to `Binary(practicedata)`

Comment: Great I understand and it's working now, thank you!